# TS: missing typings for optional members in implementation of abstract class that implements interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

Playground code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IFoo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3F%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20AbstractFoo%20implements%20IFoo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%20%3D%2042%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20baz%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ConcreteFoo1%20extends%20AbstractFoo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20for%20%22foo%22%20isn't%20checked%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20string%3B%20%2F%2F%20type%20for%20%22bar%22%20is%20checked%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ConcreteFoo2%20extends%20AbstractFoo%20implements%20IFoo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo(arg%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20expected%20error%20when%20implementing%20IFoo%20explicitly%0D%0A%7D)

Example:

```
interface IFoo {
    bar: number;
    foo?: () => void;
}

abstract class AbstractFoo implements IFoo {
    bar = 42;
};
```

Since `foo` is optional, I don't need to implement it in `AbstractFoo`. However, I can implement it in a child of `AbstractFoo`. Therefore I expect the following code to not compile since `foo` implemented wrong:

```js
class ConcreteFoo1 extends AbstractFoo {
    foo: string; // type for "foo" isn't checked
}
```

But TS doesn't do any type-checking for optional members of `IFoo`. Unless I implement it explicitly. Then compiler will perform type-checking as expected:

```js
class ConcreteFoo2 extends AbstractFoo implements IFoo {
    foo(arg: number) { } // error when implementing IFoo explicitly
}
```

**So my question is**: Why typescript don't implicitly implement interface IFoo for concrete classes? Is there some way to enforce this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's type error in how `AbstractFoo` implements `IFoo`, this results in error. `IFoo` is not related to `AbstractFoo` type and types that extend it in any other way. It doesn't enforce `foo` property type on its children because they are unaware of the fact that `AbstractFoo` implements `IFoo`.

This is a way how `IFoo` can affect children class:

```
class ConcreteFoo extends AbstractFoo implements IFoo {...}
```

If proper inheritance should be set up, this means that `IFoo` should be a class, too:

```
abstract class AbstractFoo {
    bar: number;
    foo?: () => void;
}

abstract class BaseFoo extends AbstractFoo {
    bar = 42;
};

class ConcreteFoo extends BaseFoo {...}
```